# Get checked out items that don't have checkedin version (yet)

Tags: list-item, csom

In a document library, I need to get all the files/items, even the items that don't have yet checked-in versions. Is this possible and how? I'm using CSOM (C#).

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve, your title nor the question body is very easy to comprehend right now

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Much better, I've reopened it